# Fetching data of a background task from main thread

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Here I have got a global variable which stores the index of a for loop. It's a long running process so the for each is done inside a `Task`. Inside that `Task` the index value is stored into a variable. While the background process runs I have another method which gets the value from the global variable. But it returns incorrect.

```
int myCount = -1;
Task BackgroundTask;
List<int> Count = new List<int>();

protected void Run_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundTask = new Task(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                myCount = myCount + 1;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        });
    BackgroundTask.Start();
}

protected void Check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Count.Add(myCount);            
}
```

Here while accessing the value of the variable `myCount` always returns -1 when done with `Check_Click` method. But the thread is still running. Why is it so and how can I get the count value without making the variable static?

Comment: This code is working as you intended it to work. Are you sure you are "clicking" Run before you are "clicking" Check? I.e the task actually needs to be running before trying to inspect the altered `myCount` value.

Comment: yes I have clicked Run before check.and as the thread sleeps for 1sec it will not just run out the loop quickly

Comment: Try posting a complete example, maybe in a gist. I created simple test case using a WinForms application, with the exact code above, and it works as you intended.

Comment: I too tried the exact code within a windows form application...But myCount value always shows -1 on clicking Check button.Did u try by making the variable static

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to compiler optimizations. try marking your index variable definition with volatile keyword which informs the compiler about the fact that multiple threads will access the variable.

```
volatile int myCount = -1;
Task BackgroundTask;
//rest of the code
```